# How can we zoom / pan of the graph on canvas with html5 and javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, zooming, pan

On canvas grid I drawn square and created one circle on that square.
But when I click on zoom button then canvas grid, square and circle gets zoomed. 
I just want to zoom canvas grid and square but not dot/circle, dot/circle need to translate its position with respect to scale.
 Facing problem in rescaling the circle and translating it with respect to Zoom.
Similar to google map want to achieve Zoom and Pan feature.

I got ref http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434.
But I dont want to use d3.js.

Reference :[How can we zoom in and out of the graph in html5 and javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494631/how-can-we-zoom-in-and-out-of-the-graph-in-html5-and-javascript)   --- > It is given example using actionscript. I want Javascript.

****** how to rescale shape to 1 ?
Is any references / guidence?

Comment: On a general note, it might be better to start from an example that does what you want instead of trying to adapt things that don't do what you want.